# 'Immediate' window for IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 9 and I'm curious if there is any IntelliJ equivalent of the Visual Studio 'immediate' debug window.  There is selecting the desired expression in the editor, then <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd> to evaluate the expression, but I'd like to be able to write code in a window that interacts with what I am currently debugging (if that's even possible).

Having breakpoints that log messages to the console is helpful, but I'd like to do more than that if I can.

Comment: Or, select the expression you want to evaluate, right-click, 'Evaluate expression'

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Intellij IDEA's Expression Evaluation dialog has a button to enable *Code Fragment Mode*, which permits multi-statement evaluations. (I'm using version 9.0.2 of the Ultimate Edition.)

Comment: Cool, never noticed that button before.

Answer (score 51):

Same as @Noel answer, but some more details. First of all, *Expression Evaluation* (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>) can be enabled **only in debug mode**.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 23):

**IntelliJ IDEA 13** Community Edition, Windows:

1. Go to **Debug mode** and run the application
2. Go to **Evaluate Expression**:

   [image]

   or right click in the editor area:

   [image]
3. Go to **Code Fragment Mode**
   [image]
4. Type your statements and click on **Evaluate**
   [image]

Answer (score 12):

FYI for anyone looking for this in 2019: I tried to do this in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 (Ultimate Edition) but couldn't find Code Fragment Mode button in the Expression Evaluation Dialog.

As documented [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000664524--Code-Fragment-button-missing): It is now the tiny two arrows pointing away from each other diagonally at the end of the expression box.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can write code in alt-f8.. but you have to do it only 1 line at a time. If you do a return, your code will return when you hit next (I think).  It isn't ideal though...