# Run simple programs w/o making a new class in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I often need to run simple (one/two-line) programs to quickly get the output of a method I'm developing. However, to do so I need to create a new class, add a main method, and write the code there.

I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do this, because I do this quite often.

An example would be:

```
FormatHelper.format("\\1Does \\2This work?");
```

I know there needs to be some kind of context for a program to run (classpath, etc.), but I was thinking IntelliJ could handle it for me.

Comment: By the way, many languages provide so-named *REPL*. Some has it as command line utility, some has IDE support. Example could be [Scala REPL (worksheet) for IntelliJ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2012/12/04/scala-worksheet/). I'm mentioning Scala, because you can run above code without any modifications at all. Most code will require only minor changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the [Groovy Shell](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/groovy-shell.html) from the Tools menu and run the expression there. Java expressions will work just fine.

Comment: Just what I needed! It works with the rest of the source perfectly, and I can even write several lines of code!

Comment: If found an even better solution, [Java REPL](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7215?pr=idea). However, I keep your answer as accepted, because yours doesn't need a plugin

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you described, but check out this question: ['Immediate' window for IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112363/immediate-window-for-intellij)

It appears to be related, and indicates that in IntelliJ 9 "There is ALT-F8 to evaluate an expression"

Comment: It is not exactly what I wanted because you must be running the program, and pause it in order to open that window. However, it is a pretty useful feature anyway

Answer (score 0):

I just often hold a Test Class on a test package and do everything algorithm testing-related inside my main method there.

But to directly answer your question, AFAIK no IDE will do what you want.

On a side note, it may be worth trying [ideone](http://ideone.com/) or [compileonline](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php)

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I end up doing, and I guess I'll have to keep doing it (or maybe write a plugin - although I have never written one)

Answer (score 0):

You should use http://ideone.com/ which is an online IDE.

Just write your one line code and hit run button

Comment: Although these online IDEs are useful for trying a particular piece of code, it gets really hard to import a big project into them, so that I can test one of the methods.

Comment: Well, the question was about testing two lines of code, so online ide works fine for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is an IntelliJ IDEA plugin called [Java REPL](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7215?pr=idea), which implements exactly what I was looking for.

The only downside (if you can call it a downside) is that you have to install a plugin